# How to locate which libraries are incompatible? problem when trying to update spring boot

Tags: java, spring, gradle, dependencies

Is there any way that will help me check which one library is not working with the new spring?
I'm trying to update spring in my project from 2.2.0.RELEASE to 2.2.5.RELEASE

parts of my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE")
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
}
```

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-context-support')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-jms')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.2.7.RELEASE")
    compile('org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11')
    compile('com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine')
    testCompile('org.assertj:assertj-core')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.2.7.RELEASE")
    testCompile('org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.2.0')
    testCompile('org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:2.2.0')
    testCompile('org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.2.0:test')
    testCompile('org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:2.2.0:test')
}
```

After i changed *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin* and *org.springframework.boot* to 2.2.5.RELEASE versions i'm getting these errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.assignableCheckFailed(Assert.java:673)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:604)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:635)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:433)
    ... 16 more
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

And ofcourse Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I suspect that some libraries are incompatible. But how do you check it? Maybe you had a similar problem. I've already tried many combinations

Comment: Remove the versions of the Spring Kafka dependencies (Spring Boot can manage those) as well as the `org.apache.kafka` dependency versions. Remove the `spring-context` and `spring-jms` dependencies those are already in the different starters you use. Finally you aren't showing ALL the dependencies as you also have some Spring Cloud dependencies in your list (that is what is being failed on).

Comment: What I would do is: follow the documentation. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html